# Ruby on Rails3 How to filter data by user without changing too much existing code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter

I am using Rails 3.0.9

My project is just created for a single group people. Now i want to enhance my project to enable multiple groups access. In my database, i will added a new columns both in my users table and activities table.
Schema changes:
table: users
id,
name,
group_id # new added

table: activities
id,
activity_name,
group_id # new added

Now, if users.group_id is 1, on activity page, user can only see data with activities.group_id = 1

Since there are hurge amount of code and logic there and i don't want to change control and view. This data filter also happened on other tables.
I know there is a way to use  current_user.activities.find(:all), but it will affect almost all code in my project.

Is there any way to config data filter with specific users without changing much code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try scopes? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes and default scope http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#applying-a-default-scope

Comment: scopes is the way to go, but i would discourage using default_scope. It can lead to unexpected side effects. As a quick answer : you _have_ to change at least your controller code - this problem is not only business logic but also presentation logic. There is no magic way to automaticly support a change in your specs ! This is why the use of scopes is encouraged : if your business logic already uses them, you should just have to modify them. On the other hand, if all your "find" logic is in your controllers, you're gonna have a bad time.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the tenancy Gem.
https://github.com/yoolk/tenancy

If you set Group.current = group, it adds where group_id = Group.current.id to all of your queries where an object is scoped_to group.

It's pretty clean, adds ~3 lines of code to each of your models. My application_controller sets Group.current after Devise login. (another ~3 lines of code)